# How to load a lot of data from database to pdf in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, pdf

I have a table in a SQL Server database with 11 columns and over 500,000 rows, and they need to be saved in a `.PDF` document.

Now I use in my asp.net web application "MigraDoc", but I get an "OutOfMemory" exception during building document for `PdfDocumentRenderer`.

Is any alternative way to save so much data to a `.pdf` without upgrading hardware?

Comment: can you create a stored procedure an return the data in smaller increments keeping track of the last Primary Key that was returned? you will need to do this in increments / chunks 500,000 is  lot of rows to try and retrieve at one time..  I would also recommend looking at `ITextSharp.dll` to create the pdf as well..

Comment: You are probably building the PDF in memory, you should create it on disk if your library supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fetch your data by parts. If you use EF it will be something like this:

```
var pathToFile = "D:\\example.pdf";
var pdfDoc = new PdfDoc(pathToFile); //change it to library that you use for Pdf
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var fetchCount = 100000; //take size that your hardware can handle with
    var rowCount = db.YourTableName.Count();
    double stepsCount = (rowCount + 0.0)/fetchCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount/fetchCount; i++)
    {
        var rowsToAdd = db.YourTableName.Skip(i*fetchCount).Take(fetchCount);
        pdfDoc.Append(rowsToAdd); //Use your library method
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it works. Here is my example
`var skip = 0;
var take = ListWithAllData.Count-skip > 50000 ? 50000 : ListWithAllData.Count;
do
{
AddDataTable(ref pdfDoc, ListWithAllData.Skip(skip).Take(take));
skip += take;
take = ListWithAllData.Count - skip > 50000 ? 50000 : ListWithAllData.Count - skip;
} while (skip!=ListWithAllData.Count);`

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a similar issue before. I'm taking a wild guess by saying you're currently storing all that data to a data table, resulting in the OutOfMemory exception?

The best approach would be to use a data-reader. You should then be able to stream the data and add the records to the PDF, row by row.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code. I am writing 500,000 rows in pdf document. Don't forget to use ITextSharp.

```
   Sub ExportGridViewToPDF(Response As HttpResponse, ReportTitle As String, SubTitle As String)
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf")
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
    Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
    pdfDoc.Open()
    Dim c As New Chunk(ReportTitle & vbLf, FontFactory.GetFont("Segoe UI", 14))
    Dim p As New Paragraph()
    p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
    p.Add(c)
    Dim chunk1 As New Chunk(SubTitle & vbLf, FontFactory.GetFont("Segoe UI", 8))
    Dim empty As New Chunk(" ")
    Dim p1 As New Paragraph()
    p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
    p1.Font.SetStyle("underline")
    p1.Add(chunk1)
    pdfDoc.Add(p)
    pdfDoc.Add(p1)
    pdfDoc.Add(empty)

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append(" <table>")
    sb.Append("<tr>")
    sb.Append("<th>test</th>")
    sb.Append("</tr>")
    For i As Integer = 0 To 500000
        sb.Append("<tr><td>" & i & "</td></tr>")
    Next
    sb.Append("</table>")
    For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    Next
    Dim sr As New StringReader(sb.ToString())
    htmlparser.Parse(sr)
    pdfDoc.Close()
    Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    Response.End()
End Sub

Private Sub test_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles test.Click
    ExportGridViewToPDF(Response, "test", "sub title")
End Sub
```

The trick is in following for loop:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To 1000
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    Next
```

by repeatedly sleeping thread for a second will give temporary relief to system resources and will stop 'System.OutOfMemoryException' exception.
You can use SQLDataReader to fetch records from database. Because SQLDataReader is forward only so it is faster approach to fetch data from database.

Comment: StringReader always return Exception **"Illegal character"** even wih you example, but for-loop and ITextSharp was usefull. I use it and construction `.Skip(skip).Take(take)` to fix my problem